# How to apply Geopy in a pandas column using apply() method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, geopy

Geopy takes the following code to initialize:

```
locator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder")
geocode = RateLimiter(locator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)
```

I'm using this tutorial 'https://towardsdatascience.com/geocode-with-python-161ec1e62b89':

```
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter

# 1 - conveneint function to delay between geocoding calls
geocode = RateLimiter(locator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)
# 2- - create location column
df['location'] = df['ADDRESS'].apply(geocode)
# 3 - create longitude, laatitude and altitude from location column (returns tuple)
df['point'] = df['location'].apply(lambda loc: tuple(loc.point) if loc else None)
# 4 - split point column into latitude, longitude and altitude columns
df[['latitude', 'longitude', 'altitude']] = pd.DataFrame(df['point'].tolist(), index=df.index)
```

The column `'Cidade'` on my my Dataframe `'df'` has all the names of the cities I want to find out the Latitudes and Longitudes, but when I try to apply `'geocode'` on my column it takes forever:

```
tqdm.pandas()
df['location'] = df['Cidade'].progress_apply(geocode)
```

output:

> 0%|          | 38/915078 [00:43<296:11:19,  1.17s/it]

How can I do this more effectively?

Comment: If the geocoder using internet service to fetch the info? Have you tried how long it takes to geocode just one entry?

Comment: `tqdm_notebook()
tqdm_notebook(geocode('Abelardo Luz'))` like this?

Comment: '0%
0/2 [00:00<?, ?it/s]' it doens't even starts